# Are there credits to claim in Form 1040 for 2011?

Tags: united-states, taxes

1. I remember that one year ago, when reporting federal tax using Form
   1040 for 2010, I claimed $400 of making work pay credit.

   I didn't see that item in Form 1040 of 2011. I wonder if there is
   indeed no such an item any more?
2. Are there other new credits for 2011 compared to for 2010?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Making Work Pay" credit was for years 2009 and 2010 as part of the financial stimulus act. There are no specific new credits (there are still all the usual credits like EIC, foreign tax, overpayments, and many others, those are not related to the stimulus act and haven't expired).